# Any connection between Isaiah 40:3 and the story of Ya'akov's name changed to Yisrael?

Tags: commentaries, vayishlach, isaiah-yeshaya-the-book, jacob

Regards the name changing from Ya'akov to Yisrael the Kli Yakar states that the name Yisrael comes from the word Yashar El, to be straight with G-d. This transformation is compared to Yeshayahu 40:4 'the crooked shall be made straight', he'akov (Ya'akov) l'mishor (from yashar = Yashar El).

But now I noticed something in the previous verse Yeshayahu 40:3 which uses the word panu. I noticed the same letters in Bereshit 32:32 when Ya'akov after he wrestled a malach named the place where the battle occured pni'el/pnu'el. Moreover the root yashar also is used in this verse. While the word m'silah reminded me of 2 Divrei Hayamim 9:11 and the shulam in the dream of Ya'akov.

I will admit it's a little bit far fetched, but is there any connection to Ya'akov like in the verse of Yeshayahu 40:4, or does 40:3 in no way relates itself to the story of Ya'akov? Does it teaches us anything about the way Ya'akov became straight? When Ya'akov was in this desolated place, did he made his ways free (panu), or did he straighten out his ways (yasharu) in order to turn his crookedness into yashar-el?